# Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")

Tags: php, laravel

I try install voyager admin package in my Laravel project using GitHub.

it has 3 steps to do it.it step 3 I have this error:

```
Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      B:\xampp\htdocs\gholi\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:144

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      B:\xampp\htdocs\gholi\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:142

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Answer (score 5):

In app/providers/AppServiceProvider, add:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line into your `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Further information: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;